# Django ImageFiled thumbnail from video

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

I need to make a thumbnail from a video and save it to Django's ImageField.

I already have the working code which saves the thumbnail to a specified folder but what I want is to redirect the output of FFmpeg directly to Imagefield (or to a in memory uploaded file and then to Imagefield)

This is my current code:

```
def clean(self):
    video_file = self.files['file']
    output_thumb = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'post/videos/thumbs', video_file.name)
    video_input_path = video_file.temporary_file_path()
    subprocess.call(
        ['ffmpeg', '-i', video_input_path, '-ss', '00:00:01', '-vf', 'scale=200:220', 
        '-vframes', '1', output_thumb])
    self.instance.video = video_file
    self.instance.video_thumb = output_thumb
```

Model:

```
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post/videos/', blank=True,
                         validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'webm'])])
video_thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='post/videos/thumbs', blank=True)
```

I'd like to do it so that I wouldn't need to specify the folder to save the thumb in (`output_thumb` in the code) and for Django to save it automatically using the `upload_to='post/videos/thumbs` option in the model definition

Please point me in the right direction of how to do this.

Comment: What's the format of the image file? (png/jpg/etc)?

Comment: @kesh jpg format

Comment: Could you please share your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to get it to work. Not sure if it's the right way to do this but looks like it's working. Would be grateful is someone could add  something about it.

```
file.seek(0)
args = ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'pipe:0', '-ss', '00:00:01', '-vf', 'scale=200:220',
        '-vframes', '1', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-c', 'mjpeg', 'pipe:1']
ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output_stream = ffmpeg_process.communicate(file.read())
self.instance.video = self.files['file']
self.instance.video_thumb = ContentFile(content=output_stream[0], name=filename)
```

Comment: You can shorten your code by using `subprocess.run` function as I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your self-answer, you can compact your code a bit more:

```
file.seek(0)
args = ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'pipe:0', '-ss', '00:00:01', '-vf', 'scale=200:220',
        '-vframes', '1', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-c', 'mjpeg', 'pipe:1']
content = subprocess.run(args, input=file, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
self.instance.video = self.files['file']
self.instance.video_thumb = ContentFile(content=output_stream[0], name=filename)
```

[original answer below]

Here is an partial answer. To get the ffmpeg output as `bytes`, specify the image format and codec and pipe it to `stdout`:

```
bytes = subprocess.run(
        ['ffmpeg', '-i', video_input_path, '-ss', '00:00:01', '-vf', 'scale=200:220', 
        '-vframes', '1', -f image2pipe -c mjpeg -],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I don't know Django to comment on what to do with this data here on out

Comment: Was getting an error ''bytes' object has no attribute 'fileno '. Had to change 'stdin=file' to 'input=file'

Comment: Ah, I guessed wrongly that `file` is an io object. Use `input=file` argument instead (post edited)